# Altitude value in iphone 3GS

Tags: iphone

I am using CLLocation to get altitude values. It is working fine with iphone4. But it takes long time to get the value in iphone 3GS (more than 5 min). I checked it using wi-fi on and off. In both cases, the output is same. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the `CLLocationAccuracy` when you configure the `CLLocationManager`.
It may changed the time needed to get a value, but in all case it depends on where you are and on the available GSM issuer and/or GPS satellites.

In all case, the altitude value isn't very reliable.

Comment: I am using kCLLocationAccuracyBest because my client needs the accurate position. Also the altitude values received varies every time. The best verticalAccuracy I receive is 113 using wi-fi and 230 without wi-fi.

Comment: I had the same kind of problem, but you can't have a more precise value, the devices aren't made to work as an altimeter.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely normal. In general, you should expect that the iPhone 4 GPS signal reception is far better than on the iPhone 3GS, that is far better than on the iPhone 3G:

iPhone 4 >= iPhone 3GS >= iPhone 3G

This means that on the iPhone 3GS, respect to the iPhone 4:

1) it takes longer to get the fix

2) it takes longer to get an accurate position

3) it takes longer to get an accurate altitude